# Setting default public address book in OWA

Tags: email, exchange-2003, outlook, outlook-web-app, user-settings

There are currently many different public address books (one for each site) in Outlook Web Access.

Is there a way for the user to set a different default address book for themselves to save them scrolling through the long list of sites?

Comment: Which version of exchange is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [msExchBaseDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817218) attribute, although users cannot easily change the value themselves if they want a different address list later. To make bulk changes easier, consider these [short PowerShell scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/dgoldman/archive/2009/01/08/how-to-set-the-msexchquerybasedn-via-powershell.aspx) (the first of which will run using PowerShell against Exchange 2003).

Answer (score 0):

In Options (within OWA) I have "Contact Options" (3rd from the end) where I can specify the default list.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: Unfortunately not as this only specify's a default from contact list the user has created not public address books (unless you can link the two?).